# how to handle conditional statements in echo"<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>";?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a intern and a newbie at PHP.

I have a table with columns namely  `datetime`, `status` and `val`. val column having values of either 1 or 0.I have to choose datetime , status along with their val's but while showing output in tabular format it should display ON for value 1 and OFF for value 0.

I wanted it to do it either by `if...else` or by ternary operator. Please tell me that how can do this in this `<td>...</td>` in which I'm calling a column Val from my table.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='3' align='centre' width='70%'>
                         <caption ><b>  DAILY STATUS REPORT</b></caption>
                                <TR ALIGN='CENTER'  bgcolor='#818585'>
                                <TH colspan='2'>Encapsulation Area</TH><br>
                                </TR><br>
                                <tr  bgcolor='#818585'>
                                <Th>DateAndTime</Th>
                                <Th>AHU STATUS</Th>
                                </tr>";
                     while($row1 = $result4->fetch_array()){
                        echo " <tr ALIGN='CENTER' bgcolor='#B0B4B4'>
                               <td>".$row1['DateAndTime']."</td>
                               <td>".$row1['Val']."</td>
                               </tr>";
                                }
                echo "</table>";`
```

this code is working good for me as it gives output as

> datetime  | status
>
> 2014-12-03 |  1

I want to replace that 1 with ON and if status is 0 then OFF should be displayed.

Comment: Try Write <td>".if($row1['Val'] == 1){'ON';}else{'OFF';}."</td> instead of  <td>".$row1['Val']."</td>.

Comment: okies..thanks for ur reply anant..I will check it and let you know:))

Comment: hey..it is showing an error as- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\wamp\www\reports\statusreport.php on line 151

Comment: before if add <?php  and after {'OFF';} add ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<td>".$row1['Val']."</td>
```

make it

```
<td>".($row1['Val'] == 1 ? 'On' : 'Off')."</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$row1['Val'] == 1 ? 'ON' : 'OFF"
```

Comment: thanks mike for ur reply but it is showing 
OFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFFOFF  just above the table and outputted table contains nothing..actually I have already tried both of the above ans before posing my que. here

Comment: try this: ( $row1['Val'] == 1 ? 'ON' : 'OFF' )